# Demographic simulation via arbitrary set of centiles using SQL

Tags: sql, database, test-data, frequency-distribution, data-generation

As the title suggests, I'd like to take some test data & mold it into a convincing `demographic sample.`

In a table of `centile rankings` I have an arbitrary distribution pattern, 21 rows describing centiles set at intervals of 5 that describe the `frequency distribution` of rankings.

In this manner demographic profiling can be modeled according to taste, but this technique can be applied to any sort of simulation, with any number of tiered frequency distributions. If the resulting data are too granular & more atomicity is desired, then random values can created that fit within each centile range.

```sql
centile  frequency
-------- -----------
0        0
5        1
10       2
/~~~~~~~~~~~/
40       7
45       8
50       8
55       9
60       8
/~~~~~~~~~~~/
90       3
95       2
100      1
```

As the simplest case, I want to populate this distribution into a pre-existing set of test data ("student records") **randomly** assigning each centile grouping *(80th, 85th, 90th...)*  to the appropriate # of student records *(10 students, 5 students, 3 students...)*.

```sql
id          lname      fname      dob        centile
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
1           Bender     Brooke     2016-10-07      5
2           Chan       Raya       2016-07-27     10
3           Acosta     Jared      2017-02-15     10
/~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/  
98          Maddox     Cassady    2016-09-01     95
99          Mcdonald   Heather    2018-02-20     95
100         Todd       Sydnee     2017-03-12    100
```

In practice I'd want to target any number of student records, with the centiles proportionally assigned. Each set of 21 frequency distributions would evince different patterns, even highly skewed distributions *(exponential, Weibull, Laplace),* each tailored as a predefined user-set pattern.

DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE centiles
 (
      frequency int
     , centile int
) ;

CREATE TABLE student ( 
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)  
      ,lastname varchar(255) 
      ,firstname varchar(255)
      ,dob date );

INSERT INTO centiles
 (centile, frequency)
 VALUES
(    0           ,    0           )
,(    5           ,    1           )
,(    10          ,    2           )
,(    15          ,    3           )
,(    20          ,    3           )
,(    25          ,    4           )
,(    30          ,    5           )
,(    35          ,    6           )
,(    40          ,    7           )
,(    45          ,    8           )
,(    50          ,    8           )
,(    55          ,    9           )
,(    60          ,    8           )
,(    65          ,    8           )
,(    70          ,    7           )
,(    75          ,    6           )
,(    80          ,    5           )
,(    85          ,    4           )
,(    90          ,    3           )
,(    95          ,    2           )
,(    100         ,    1           );


INSERT INTO Students 
( [LastName],[FirstName],[dob]) 
VALUES
 ( 'Bender','Brooke','2016-10-07')
, ( 'Chan','Raya','2016-07-27')
, ( 'Acosta','Jared','2017-02-15')
, ( 'Chase','Leah','2017-09-05')
, ( 'Jefferson','Giselle','2016-09-15')
, ( 'Paul','Sage','2017-04-02')
, ( 'Mckinney','Shaine','2018-02-15')
, ( 'Key','Bertha','2016-05-12')
, ( 'Donovan','Morgan','2016-10-25')
, ( 'Graves','Gil','2016-07-14')
, ( 'Chan','Hilel','2016-08-02')
, ( 'Davenport','Mollie','2017-04-08')
, ( 'Mccoy','Ayanna','2016-07-18')
, ( 'Head','Camden','2016-06-25')
, ( 'Hickman','Risa','2016-05-23')
, ( 'Salazar','Ivy','2017-05-22')
, ( 'Hyde','Kane','2017-06-12')
, ( 'Allen','Carol','2018-01-09')
, ( 'Quinn','Phillip','2016-12-21')
, ( 'Pollard','Aristotle','2017-06-16')
, ( 'Hinton','Colorado','2017-02-09')
, ( 'Howard','Nehru','2018-02-03')
, ( 'Chambers','Hillary','2016-09-08')
, ( 'Padilla','Warren','2017-05-29')
, ( 'Rutledge','Plato','2016-07-31')
, ( 'Goodman','Serina','2017-12-07')
, ( 'Bean','Stewart','2017-04-10')
, ( 'Tran','Sacha','2016-10-15')
, ( 'Schroeder','Kai','2017-10-04')
, ( 'Cooper','Phyllis','2016-11-27')
, ( 'Pierce','Madeline','2018-02-16')
, ( 'Lee','Kibo','2018-03-22')
, ( 'Robles','Libby','2016-09-03')
, ( 'Riley','Veronica','2018-03-03')
, ( 'Booth','Wynter','2018-04-09')
, ( 'Bird','Eugenia','2017-04-06')
, ( 'Morton','Ryder','2016-10-14')
, ( 'Tanner','Paloma','2017-08-25')
, ( 'Powers','Colton','2018-03-05')
, ( 'Mccarthy','Roth','2017-04-17')
, ( 'Floyd','Neve','2017-08-15')
, ( 'Mcneil','Ria','2017-11-18')
, ( 'Hoffman','Odessa','2018-03-26')
, ( 'Christian','Vanna','2016-05-16')
, ( 'Mercer','Madison','2017-01-31')
, ( 'Franks','Angela','2016-07-31')
, ( 'Obrien','Desirae','2016-08-03')
, ( 'Walls','Elmo','2017-02-25')
, ( 'Flores','Hakeem','2016-09-12')
, ( 'Waller','Demetrius','2018-02-28')
, ( 'Savage','Mara','2018-02-02')
, ( 'Wilkerson','Germane','2018-01-23')
, ( 'Ramirez','Aphrodite','2017-05-31')
, ( 'Fischer','Amery','2017-07-19')
, ( 'Sweeney','Upton','2017-01-18')
, ( 'Joyner','Simon','2017-11-18')
, ( 'Dunn','Logan','2017-04-14')
, ( 'Tyler','Shannon','2017-05-27')
, ( 'Dillard','Fritz','2016-12-28')
, ( 'Moran','Rooney','2017-12-08')
, ( 'Logan','Hunter','2016-11-06')
, ( 'Gamble','Talon','2017-04-08')
, ( 'Mckay','Quon','2017-08-22')
, ( 'Livingston','Wylie','2017-02-21')
, ( 'Hensley','Quincy','2018-01-08')
, ( 'Mcmahon','Meredith','2018-04-26')
, ( 'Flowers','Zachery','2018-01-29')
, ( 'Shepherd','Cairo','2017-01-25')
, ( 'Sweet','Sarah','2017-10-30')
, ( 'Newton','Calvin','2017-07-22')
, ( 'Cameron','Paloma','2016-09-07')
, ( 'Combs','Warren','2017-01-14')
, ( 'Ayala','Gary','2018-04-16')
, ( 'Beard','Shellie','2018-01-02')
, ( 'Witt','Anthony','2017-09-14')
, ( 'Garner','Quon','2016-06-12')
, ( 'Petersen','Maris','2017-11-20')
, ( 'Noble','Igor','2018-03-18')
, ( 'Adkins','Isaiah','2017-03-20')
, ( 'Mcclain','Gillian','2016-09-01')
, ( 'Henson','Bert','2016-06-30')
, ( 'Randall','Zeus','2018-02-26')
, ( 'Hart','Christine','2017-05-31')
, ( 'Carter','Jocelyn','2017-05-10')
, ( 'Mcfadden','Celeste','2018-03-11')
, ( 'Contreras','Abbot','2017-04-05')
, ( 'Kerr','Uriel','2016-05-06')
, ( 'Wood','Sybil','2016-12-14')
, ( 'Armstrong','Ethan','2017-09-20')
, ( 'Morse','Rae','2018-01-25')
, ( 'York','Irene','2018-04-30')
, ( 'Garrison','Thor','2016-06-20')
, ( 'Pace','Harlan','2017-02-02')
, ( 'Cleveland','Kylan','2016-06-18')
, ( 'Stanley','Roth','2016-10-28')
, ( 'Kemp','Alan','2016-11-04')
, ( 'Stewart','Frances','2017-12-13')
, ( 'Maddox','Cassady','2016-09-01')
, ( 'Mcdonald','Heather','2018-02-20')
, ( 'Todd','Sydnee','2017-03-12')
;
```

Comment: What is a "non-uniform normal distribution"?  Is this just an everyday "normal distribution" or something different?  And what does a theoretical distribution have to do with a table with an explicit distribution in it?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. And yes, I should just say "Normal distribution."

Comment: @Leebert . . . It is a good question.  However, it has nothing to do with any theoretical  distribution, because you have the actual distribution approximated in the centiles table.  It does not matter how it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

So, calculate a cumulative distribution for the values.  Use this to calculate the lower and upper bounds in the distribution for each centile.  Then the tricky part is calculating a random number in SQL Server.

But the rest is just a join:

```
with c as (
      select c.*,
             ((sum(frequency) over (order by centile) - frequency) / sum(frequency * 1.0) over ()) as lb,
             (sum(frequency) over (order by centile) / sum(frequency * 1.0) over ()) as ub
      from centiles c
     )
select s.*, c.centile
from (select s.*,
             rand(checksum(newid())) as randish
      from students s
     ) s join
     c
     on s.randish >= c.lb and s.randish < s.ub;
```

I should note:  There may be other ways to generate random numbers apart from `rand(checksum(newid()))`.  That works well enough in practice.

Comment: Gordon - every version of SQL Server I tried this on (2008R2-2016) complained about the syntax - I think you were missing a bracket and had an extra one elsewhere, hope you don't mind me adjusting to what I think you meant!

Comment: This generated 1000's of duplicate records. Sorry about that.

Comment: What happens if you use `rand(s.id)` rather than `rand(checksum(newid()))`?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. However I really like the selectiveness of the other technique. You seem to be in the thick of the field, pls. give it a try (the DDL is posted as well). To me this answers a lot of problems with building simulation & test data quickly w/out having to write loop & seek SP's.

Answer (score 0):

This first method (I suspect there are others) is actually pretty straightforward:

1. Expand the centile set from 21 records to 100 (101) & give each frequency descriptor a random row identifier

   ```sql
   -- use Common Table Expression to materialize frequencies
   with expanded AS  -- CTE
    ( 
       SELECT centile
           ,frequency
       FROM centiles -- original records
       UNION ALL
       SELECT centile  -- a functional group
           ,frequency - 1 -- decrement
       FROM expanded  -- spawn additional 80 freq. def'ns
       WHERE frequency > 1 -- just the ones that need more

       )
   SELECT 
   expanded.centile
   ,expanded.frequency
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn_newid  -- give them arbitrary row id
   into #z_centiles_expanded
   from expanded ;
   ```

   2. Join them to a set of student records.

      ```sql
      select s.id
      , zt1.centile
      , zt1.frequency as freq_sub  -- 1...n
      , c.frequency as centile_freq -- n
          from #z_centiles_expanded zt1 
              join centiles c on zt1.centile = c.centile -- original freq.
              join students s on zt1.rn_newid = s.id -- rn_newid is randomish
      order by zt1.centile
                  , c.frequency
                  , zt1.frequency ;
      ```

Comment: To apply this to larger target sets, the source centile def'n table frequencies could be proportionally augmented to fit the target dataset. So if there are 10k students instead of 100, multiply all the frequencies by 100. The CTE _**expanded**_ will expand to 10k rows. 

Formula: `newfreq = oldfreq * (10000 / 100)`